# Spell Turning vs Ranged touch attacks

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, magic

The spell [Spell Turning](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spell-turning/) states that "Spell turning also fails to stop touch range spells."

Does this also apply to ranged touch spells, or specifically spells with a range of touch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the [***spell turning***](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spell-turning/) spell says that it can't stop "touch range spells," it means that the *spell turning* effect can't stop spells that have in their header information the entry ***Range** Touch* (see [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Range)). A spell that requires that the caster make a ranged touch attack typically won't have an entry of ***Range** Touch*. (Keep in mind that, as [willuwontu](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/47188/willuwontu) so kindly reminded me, the *spell turning* effect also can't stop area spells or effect spells, the latter including most rays, from *scorching* to *polar*.)

Thus a *spell turning* effect can normally turn a spell like [*battering blast*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/battering-blast/) or [*mark of the reptile god*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mark-of-the-reptile-god/) that sees the caster make a ranged touch attack, but it normally can't turn a spell like [*vampiric touch*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/vampiric-touch/) or [*imprisonment*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/imprisonment/) that has an entry of ***Range** Touch*.